# Testing nodejs app with Advanced Rest Client

Tags: node.js, rest

The service I want to test, in a MEAN application:

```
app.post('/post_employee', function (req,res) {
        var emp_temp = new Employee ({
            name: req.params.name,
            birthDate: req.params.birthDate,
            phoneNumber: req.params.phoneNumber,
            email: req.params.email,
            entryDate: req.params.entryDate,
            sendMail: req.params.sendMail,
            sendSMS: req.params.sendSMS,
            facebookPost: req.params.facebookPost
        });
        emp_temp.save(function(err, emp){
            if ( err )
                return console.error(err);
            else
                return console.log("Employee inserted correctly");
        });
    });
```

I can acess the app with localhost:4242, no problem there.

I'm trying to test it with Advanced Rest Client.

Path is localhost:4242/post_employee

Type is POST

Raw payload is

```
{
   name : "pdero", 
   birthDate: Date.now(), 
   phoneNumber : "12345678", 
   email : "email@server.com" ,
   entryDate : Date.now(), 
   sendMail: false,
   sendSMS: true, 
   facebookPost: false
}
```

Raw header is `Content-Type: application/json`

Result is `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put `http://` in front of localhost:4242